# Concatenate attributes in Symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony-forms

I have a `symfony` form of following structure.

```
if (!$propertyId) {
        $form->add('room-type', 'choice', [
            'label' => false,
            'choices' => $this->di->get("roomType")->getRoomByPropertyId($propertyId),
            'placeholder' => 'All Room types',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'room-type-id hidden']
        ]);
    } else {
        $form->add('room-type', 'choice', [
           'label' => false,
           'choices' => $this->di->get("roomType")->getRoomByPropertyId($propertyId),
           'placeholder' => 'All Room types',
           'attr' => ['class' => 'room-type-id']
        ]);
    }
```

I want to refactor this so that I can concatenate the `hidden` attribute if `propertyId` is `null`.

Something like this and various other combinations that I have tried is not working.

`['class' => 'room-type-id' + isset($propertyId) ? '' : 'hidden']`

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using this code.

`'attr' => isset($propertyId) ? ['class' => 'room-type-id'] : ['class' => 'room-type-id hidden']`

Comment: I am totally agains one liners. They are difficult to debug when you have a problem and you can spend days until you find it.. this is why I recommend to create a method with a self explanatory name.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have that code in a controller. Would be better to move the form logic inside it's own class and then add a private method inside it.

```
private function createChoiceClass($propertyId)
{
    $class = 'room-type-id';
    if (!empty($propertyId) {
        $class .= ' hidden';
    }

    return $class;
}
```

Then in build method

```
$form->add(
    ....
    'attr' => ['class' => $this->createChoiceClass($propertyId)],
);
```

you can see here how to create a form class https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Working with form classes is much easier to maintain than if you do it in controller

Comment: This is a function for `preset` and `presubmit` events